# CKEditor: Como deixar as imagens responsivas?

Tags: imagem, layout-responsivo, ckeditor

Pessoal criei um site do zero e integrei ao CKEditor, meu site está em Bootstrap mas as imagens que envio pelo CKEditor não estão responsivas, já instalei um plugin ([imageresponsive](http://ckeditor.com/addon/imageresponsive)) mas não sei o que colocar no inputs `sourceset` e `sizes`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que plugin é esse? Sem saber qual é o plugin, nem que código ele gera, fica difícil de saber o que pode estar acontecendo. O nome *"sourceset"* me remete ao [elemento `picture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) (que não é padronizado, e nem todo *browser* suporta), mas não sei se é isso mesmo que o plugin está usando ou se é outra coisa. Não há nada na documentação desse plugin que diga como usar?

Comment: @mgibsonbr é esse plugin, ele requer outros plugin para funcionar... http://ckeditor.com/addon/imageresponsive

Comment: Pelo jeito esse `srcset` não tem nada a ver com o `picture`, [ele é um atributo do `img` mesmo...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) O mesmo vale pro `sizes`. Nunca tinha visto esses atributos antes, então ainda não sei bem o que eles fazem, mas assim que der vou ler mais sobre o assunto (achei [uma explicação](https://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/) - em inglês, e um bocado longa - depois se ninguém der uma resposta melhor vou tentar resumi-lo aqui).

Answer (score 1):

Esse plugin parece estar utilizando os novos atributos `srcset` e `sizes` do elemento `img`. Aqui está [a especificação](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-img-srcset), e [o conjunto de *browsers* que já dão suporte a eles](http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset).

Sobre o que colocar nos campos, assumindo que cada campo se refere ao atributo correspondente, eu diria o seguinte:

- URL: a URL da imagem "padrão", caso o *browser* não dê suporte ao `srcset`;
- Sourceset: uma lista com duas ou mais imagens "candidatas", cada imagem acompanhada de sua largura em pixels ou seu *device-pixel-ratio*. Exemplo:

  ```
  imagem1.jpg 100w, imagem2.jpg 200w, imagem3.jpg 400w
  ```

  ou

  ```
   imagemA.jpg 1x, imagemB.jpg 1.5x, imagemC.jpg 2x
  ```
- Sizes: uma lista com zero ou uma *media query* e a largura que a imagem deve ocupar naquelas condições. Exemplo:

  ```
  (max-width: 500px) 95vw, (max-width: 1000px) 50vw, 500px
  ```

(Nota: eu não entendo nada sobre o funcionamento de *device-pixel-ratio*, mas encontrei [um artigo](http://sergiolopes.org/resolucoes-dpi-pixel-ratio-retina/) detalhando os conceitos envolvidos.)

Um exemplo concreto seria o seguinte (veja o exemplo em "página toda" e redimensione a janela do browser para notar o efeito):

```html
<img srcset="http://placehold.it/100x25 100w,
             http://placehold.it/400x100 400w,
             http://placehold.it/1600x400 1600w,
             http://placehold.it/6400x1600 6400w"
     sizes="(max-width: 768px) 96vw,
            (max-width: 1200px) 50vw,
            33vw"
     src="http://placehold.it/400x100"
>
```

Aqui eu dou uma lista de imagens e suas larguras originais (cada uma 4 vezes maior que a anterior) e deixo o *browser* decidir qual delas é a mais apropriada pra ser exibida. Além disso, eu estabeleço as larguras que essas imagens ocuparão de fato na página sob diversas condições (expressas como *media queries*). Por fim, uma URL alternativa pro caso do *browser* não dar suporte a nada disso.

Qual o critério que o *browser* vai usar para escolher uma imagem da lista, não sei dizer (no meu teste com o Chrome e Firefox em uma tela de PC ambos exibiram o 1600x400 não importa o quanto eu redimensionasse a tela). Ao observar o exemplo em várias condições eu cheguei à conclusão que ele vai escolher a melhor imagem **no momento da carga**, e continuar usando-a depois não importa o que aconteça. Não sei se isso é por design ou alguma limitação na implementação.

Comment: Consegui, usei esse codigo... <script type="text/javascript">
//pega todas as imagens da div com id "content" 
//retira atributo style inline das imgs adicionadas no ckeditor
//adiciona class img-responsive
  
  var images = $(".descricao img");
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
   $(".descricao img")[i].removeAttribute('style');
   $(".descricao img")[i].setAttribute("class", "img-responsive");
  }
</script>